# MFC ComboBox not editable

Tags: user-interface, visual-c++, mfc

I am populating a [ComboBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12h9x0ch.aspx) with a  list of strings to be selected from. But in addition I can select the ComboBox and edit in my own string.

How can I disabled this behavior so you can not edit the ComboBox?

Comment: Create the control with the `CBS_DROPDOWNLIST` style.

Comment: In what method of a CDialog should I call SetExtendedUI to set this flag. I am doing it in OnInitDialog, and the ComboBox is still editable...

Comment: No, nothing to do with SetExtendedUI. This is a style that you should set for the combo box when you create it. Are you creating it manually by calling a Create member function, or is it a control on a dialog template? If the former, you should be passing this flag as one of the window styles. If the latter, then you can just set the appropriate property in the dialog resource editor. It's called something like "Drop List", if I remember correctly.

Comment: How did you create the combobox? Via Resource Editor or by code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you created the combobox on the Resource Editor, you should change the combobox's `Type` to `Drop List`:

[image: Combobox Type = Drop List]

I also recommend you to have `Sort` set to `False`, so the interface shows the elements ordered as you insert them instead of some magic sorcery that makes them to appear alphabetically.

Comment: Well done for showing this visually too for the user.